# How to create watermark in the background band in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to create a watermark with a text in a report. For e.g. have a text like `this is a good report` printed horizontally repeatedly at the background of a report. I know this can be done in the background band but don't know how.

**UPDATE**
Your solution worked. I want to implement this in another way. I want to print the same text repeatedly at the background. Let's say i want to print the text `welcome to a new year`. I will want it to print this way

```
welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year
welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year
welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year
welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year
welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year welcome to a new year
...
```

All these will be at the background. Can i achieve something like this without manually creating the text fields to fill the page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can use *Background* band for printing watermark text (or picture).
You should set the ***height*** for this band - I think it is better to set height of this band the same as the report's height.

For example, for *A4* format I have set the **802** pixels for *Background's band height*. The formula for calculating this number was: *the **Report's** height (**842** pixels for **A4** format) **-** the **Left Margin's** width (**20** in my case) **-**  the **Right Margin's** width (**20** in my case)*.

After setting size for the *Background* band you can put ***image*** or ***staticText (textField)*** elements to this (*Background*) band.

You can rotate the text of ***staticText (textField)*** element with help of **rotation** attribute. The available values of this attribites are:

- *None* (no rotation - 0 degrees),
- *Left* (rotate 270 degrees),
- *Right* (rotate 90 degrees),
- *UpsideDown* (rotate 180 degrees).

In the working sample I've used *styles* for setting the **rotation** attribute for ***textField*** and for one element I've set value for this attribute directly to the ***textField*** element:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="watermark_sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bc290dd1-903c-4740-8484-16a2ebe872d2">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Rotated180" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF33CC" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" rotation="UpsideDown" fontName="Curlz MT" fontSize="40"/>
    <style name="Rotated270" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF33CC" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" rotation="Left" fontName="Curlz MT" fontSize="40"/>
    <style name="Rotated90" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF33CC" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" rotation="Right" fontName="Curlz MT" fontSize="40"/>
    <style name="NotRotated" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF33CC" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" rotation="None" fontName="Curlz MT" fontSize="40"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, NAME, COST FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY NAME]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <image hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement uuid="42c96db8-4afd-4834-ba69-6b211df0c42f" style="Rotated180" mode="Opaque" x="118" y="372" width="318" height="58"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["D:\\java\\jasper_reports\\happy_new_year_h.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d7401e33-f1b3-49ca-85d1-2923d82508f6" style="NotRotated" x="106" y="22" width="342" height="63"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Happy New Year!]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d7401e33-f1b3-49ca-85d1-2923d82508f6" style="Rotated270" x="24" y="236" width="93" height="330"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Happy New Year!]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d7401e33-f1b3-49ca-85d1-2923d82508f6" style="Rotated90" x="445" y="236" width="93" height="330"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Happy New Year!]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d7401e33-f1b3-49ca-85d1-2923d82508f6" style="Rotated180" x="106" y="702" width="342" height="63"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Happy New Year!]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3bdd5d67-94f0-457f-8477-b1d0438d7bc9" mode="Opaque" x="79" y="85" width="428" height="139" forecolor="#9999FF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Right">
                    <font fontName="Edwardian Script ITC" size="40" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Happy New Year!]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6d708618-09e4-433d-ab48-bb9cbd0b832b" x="92" y="29" width="370" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sample of report with watermark]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The ***image*** element does not support the **rotation** attribute, but you can create any image you want manually.

***Note***: in this sample I've used ***mode="Opaque"*** for ***textField*** and ***image*** elements.

The result will be (via *iReport* preview function):
[image: The generated report]

---

For solving your case (***several*** texts as watermark) I've put several ***textField*** elements to the *Background* band. The report's template is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="watermark_sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bc290dd1-903c-4740-8484-16a2ebe872d2">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="68"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, NAME, COST FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY NAME]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3bdd5d67-94f0-457f-8477-b1d0438d7bc9" mode="Transparent" x="63" y="112" width="428" height="56" forecolor="#808080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="40" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[this is a good report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3bdd5d67-94f0-457f-8477-b1d0438d7bc9" mode="Transparent" x="63" y="272" width="428" height="56" forecolor="#808080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="40" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[this is a good report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3bdd5d67-94f0-457f-8477-b1d0438d7bc9" mode="Transparent" x="63" y="432" width="428" height="56" forecolor="#808080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="40" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[this is a good report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3bdd5d67-94f0-457f-8477-b1d0438d7bc9" mode="Transparent" x="63" y="594" width="428" height="56" forecolor="#808080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="40" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[this is a good report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6d708618-09e4-433d-ab48-bb9cbd0b832b" x="92" y="29" width="370" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sample of report with watermark]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

***Note***: in this sample I've used ***mode="Transparent"*** for ***textField*** elements.

The report's design (in *iReport*):

[image]

The result will be (via *iReport* preview function):
[image: Generated report in iReport]

---

You can find more information in [Watermark across the page in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11665663/876298) post if you want to set custom rotation angle.

---

***UPDATE***: You can solve your second issue, for example, with help of [StringUtils.repeat(java.lang.String, int)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method from [Commons Lang API](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/index.html).

You can add ***import*** instruction (`<import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"/>` in my sample) to your report's template and use the expression like this:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[StringUtils.repeat("Welcome to a New Year! ", $P{numberOfRepeats})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="watermark_sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bc290dd1-903c-4740-8484-16a2ebe872d2">
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"/>
    <parameter name="numberOfRepeats" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[10]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, NAME, COST FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY NAME]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="26290245-c5cf-4f28-b637-c5b0253910a5" mode="Transparent" x="21" y="112" width="470" height="56" forecolor="#808080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="20" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[StringUtils.repeat("Welcome to a New Year! ", $P{numberOfRepeats})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6d708618-09e4-433d-ab48-bb9cbd0b832b" x="92" y="29" width="370" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sample of report with watermark]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cost]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="414160e2-41c4-4326-8ec8-ff7c230ac2c3" mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#3399FF"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5715c691-0b39-4530-9009-3b7179bb06f5" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="10">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via *iReport* preview function):

[image: Generated report in iReport]

***Details:***

- In this sample I've used the ***Commons Lang library v. 3.1***. You should add this library to the application's classpath (in my case it was *iReport*'s cp).

[image: iReport classpath]

- I've used the parameter ***numberOfRepeats*** (*java.lang.Integer*) for setting the number of phrases to generate.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu I've added the new solution for your new question.

Comment: It worked, i had to make the height and width of the `textfield` equal to the height and width of the background band.

Comment: can you try to export to HTML format ? I am getting strange results.