# Background image in the background band/detail band is being shown in design but not in preview and pdf in Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I have added Background Image by going to View -> Background Image

Below is my jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Student_GradeCard" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1af80d91-9323-421a-9eaf-ed9c9f6e6975">
    <property name="background.image.path" value="C:\path\BMSCELOGO.bmp"/>
    <property name="background.image.widht" value="257"/>
    <property name="background.image.height" value="193"/>
    <property name="background.image.x" value="324"/>
    <property name="background.image.y" value="182"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="studentName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="motherName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fatherName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="USN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Semester" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Session" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SLNo" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="dateOfIssue" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="creditsRegistered" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="creditsEarned" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="SGPA" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="cumulativeCreditsEarned" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="CGPA" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="440" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="396" uuid="a8145236-550e-4919-b555-04da6b0131c6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FA8816"/>
                </box>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement stretchType="ContainerHeight" x="12" y="12" width="779" height="374" uuid="e584ab75-ec26-4776-a40b-24dd6cd3f84a"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="4.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FA8816"/>
                    </box>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="132" y="12" width="388" height="30" forecolor="#0000AF" uuid="e84730b8-3fe1-4b36-acdf-82953272cb85"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font fontName="Lucida Bright" size="20" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[B M S COLLEGE OF ENGINEERING,]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="502" y="12" width="198" height="30" forecolor="#0000AF" uuid="052e2686-4fd5-4818-b2b6-679cc9eec4b4"/>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="Lucida Bright" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[BANGALORE - 560 019]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="136" y="42" width="566" height="16" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="53cf89c0-758d-4914-a6bf-0db81aff79b8"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="10"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[(Autonomous College under Visvesvaraya Technological University, Belgaum)]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="134" y="60" width="566" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="4bfe2a96-5be6-4ad7-94fc-09a81c7af9fb"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Karnataka, India]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="136" y="80" width="564" height="30" forecolor="#E77817" uuid="031f1e54-be88-441a-928d-5f839427d775"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font fontName="Arial" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[GRADE CARD]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="139" y="102" width="562" height="30" forecolor="#FF0000" uuid="df1b9872-b463-4131-8fd1-15448bad61ac"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="17"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Master of Technology]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="132" width="140" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="de0e642e-5342-425b-98ee-b92eb50cf702"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Name of the Student:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="152" width="140" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="b45c1157-90ab-4310-8f50-dedbde39d398"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Name of the Mother:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="172" width="140" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="bed17f85-0e82-4c23-b7e5-3dc0a5552cf3"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Name of the Father :]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="192" width="140" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="a04692a4-a492-497e-ab24-43ac459f331a"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[University Seat Number :]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="162" y="132" width="136" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="f506bd82-b67d-41da-a92b-faea3410004b"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{studentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="162" y="152" width="138" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="5dade759-f45d-4d14-af66-4474cd81e61d">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{motherName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="162" y="172" width="136" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="d22e56ec-d2ed-4cc8-a030-9edcc5c28d32">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fatherName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="162" y="192" width="136" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="a9894ed8-2970-4bc6-8a48-6418282c16a5"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{USN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <image onErrorType="Blank">
                        <reportElement x="91" y="22" width="50" height="50" uuid="0acebf72-318c-4bce-86ec-8045378dae0e"/>
                        <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\path\\BMSCELOGO.bmp"]]></imageExpression>
                    </image>
                    <image onErrorType="Blank">
                        <reportElement x="704" y="27" width="37" height="50" uuid="55def125-f8c7-4e19-86dc-23b8b4c8bbaf"/>
                        <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\path\\VTULOGO.bmp"]]></imageExpression>
                    </image>
                    <image onErrorType="Blank">
                        <reportElement x="702" y="128" width="50" height="50" uuid="fd930389-8f40-4604-a32c-584c7b7b2614"/>
                        <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\path\\"+$F{USN}+".jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                    </image>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="480" y="154" width="68" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="f49e1d7b-00e6-4387-b76b-e6d04cb7b823"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Semester:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="480" y="172" width="68" height="18" forecolor="#0C20E2" uuid="354978b8-fa85-4e1b-831b-7b7a6d9b5faa">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Session :]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="550" y="172" width="136" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="a5f88a4a-7375-484c-bbcb-180bb516ac8b"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Session}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="550" y="156" width="136" height="18" forecolor="#A52378" uuid="cecfb981-d018-419b-b661-f8936de3e6c1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Semester}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The Image added through Palette is getting displayed but background Image added through View -> Background Image is not working.

** I have also added code to the background band but still the image doesn't show in the preview nor in the pdf **

**jrxml with background band**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Student-GradeCard" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="82747cb6-07de-4c80-8914-8c3873f497a7">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="background.image.path" value="C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\BMSCE_Templates\LOGOS USED IN GC(UG,PG)\VCH1.bmp"/>
    <property name="background.image.widht" value="771"/>
    <property name="background.image.height" value="531"/>
    <property name="background.image.x" value="40"/>
    <property name="background.image.y" value="40"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band height="555" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </background>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing as they mentioned in those questions but it didn't work so can you open this question @Alex K

Comment: I don't see any image at background band (at your example). This posts contain solutions and your post duplicates this questions

Comment: I even tried adding an image to a background band but still it is not working have a look at my newly added jrxml @Alex K

Comment: I don't see any image at your new example

Comment: There is a image in the property tag above the background band if I add to the band that tag is coming above it is that fine or do I need to change something else .

Comment: Can you please explain what am I missing ? @Alex K

Comment: You can do the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14091496/876298)