# Rotate text at any degree in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* to generate *pdf*. I need to rotate text at any degree. As I read in documentation, *iReport* can rotate text at 90, 180, 270 and 360 degree. Also I want it on dynamic value.
For This I try these procedure but not get expected result.

[rotate Image using custom jar](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/526526/how-rotate-text-field-45-degrees#99620)

Its a *Java* method working fine when I try save an image and see its preview. But When I make a jar file and include this in *iReport*, I could not get any result.

I try to use css styling two types.

First I make a text field an markup it as html. Use inline css to rotate text. But its not working anymore.example is here.

```xml
<title>
    <band height="313" splitType="Stretch">
        <image>
            <reportElement uuid="c4edca6a-50d8-481f-bea0-9513268d4a88" x="13" y="13" width="150"    height="41"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.rotateText( $V{SpecialDescription},new    java.awt.Font("Sans Serif",1,100), 100, 100, 45, java.awt.Color.white)]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="22594755-7eba-4313-a1fd-41ac20dc50b5" x="141" y="101" width="234" height="53"/><textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<html><div  style=\"-moz- transform:rotate(20deg)translateX(230px)scale(1.5); -o-transform: rotate(20deg)  translateX(230px) scale(1.5);-webkit-transform:  rotate(20deg)translateX(230px)scale(1.5);transform: rotate(50deg) translateX(230px)  scale(1.5);\">Hello</div><html>"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```

Also I try to add css using html component. For this I add `htmlComponent.jar` and write code for generate it, but it is also not working.

One more thing, when I try add color an background color it give me expected color, but it did not rotate text.

Is there any another way to rotate text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark across the page in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665663/watermark-across-the-page-in-jasperreports) & [How to create watermark in the background band in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14083270/876298)

Comment: I have already seen both link. and also mention in my question whatever I tried. I just want to know that is there some another way to do this?

Comment: What version of *JasperReports* and *iReport* are you using?

Comment: japerReport 4.7.1 and also ireport 4.7.1

Comment: Try to use *iReport 5.2.0*, may be it help you. I found that *Html component* works strange in *iReport 4.x*

Comment: Do you want to say that if I will use iReport 5.2.0, and I will try to rotate using htmlComponent and css styling , so it will help to rotate text?

Comment: I said that you can try. IMHO, it is better to check your solution with *iReport 5.2.0*

Comment: Hi, I have tried on iReport just now. But it do not work yet. Is there any other idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can rotate the text to any degree using itext. You can use iText to read the pdf you created using jasper reports. Either read the pdf as byteArray if it is not already written to a pdf file, then use itext PdfReader to read the contents

I hope the following link helps you which is for watermark but can be utilized for rotating the content to a degree as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45534733/4664978

Comment: This is more a publicity than a valid answer. It doesn't answer the question about JasperReport